# How to realistically implement model for user generated forms in swing

Tags: java, forms, swing, design-patterns, model

One of the projects I'm currently working on includes a Java Swing application for field users to input data about equipment parts scattered all over the companies facilities.
Most of the data collected is measured (field validation is required) or some value the operator can choose from a predefined list.The software then does some calculation and displays back instructions to the operator.

so for example for part number 3435Af-B, engineering requires the operator to measure 
the diameter of some bolt and choose the part maker from a list. the application then compares the measured diameter to the stock diameter and tells the operator if it should be replaced (this is obviously not a real world example, but you get the idea)

The problem is there are over 200 known equipment parts and these are pretty old and heterogeneous so the engineering team has a limited idea of what they would like to measure on each part in the future. It doesn't seam reasonable to have the development team write and maintain over 200 different classes but doesn't seem realistic to have the engineers use a complicated system of form builders and BPM like drools (i'm getting sweaty just thinking about it).

We're currently trying to make a poor man's solution that would allow the engineers to build forms with a simple GUI having limited features and outputting the forms to XML files. The few complicated cases not covered by the GUI solution would be custom made by the developers (very few cases). For the calculation part, we would use Java Expression library (JEL), the expressions to evaluate would be generated by the same GUI.

Before we commit to this solution, I was wondering if there is something we could do differently to have a more robust system. I know that some people will consider this too much soft-coding and I agree that it is going to be difficult extracting and treating the data.